# how to bypass an HVAC unit float switch (safe-t-switch)

Tags: hvac

Rats keep chewing through the safe-t-switch wires even when I taped them up heavy. Before I get rid of all the rats, I need to just bypass the float switch. At least then, I can use the heat while I'm home.

Comment: Why not put in some armor clad or metal flex and run the wiring through that. Safety switches are important and keep the system from flooding the home when used. You might be surprised at the amount of water your unit creates.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is short the wires together: cut the wires, strip them and twist them together.

Or, trace the wires back to where they hook up in your air handler and connect them together there.

Answer (score 2):

Safe t switch is an add on feature to an hvac system if I'm thinking of the right thing. If that's the case then yes you can easily bypass it by removing it completely and joining the two remaining wires coming out of the furnace.